# Vue download file from link href and Vuetify v-btn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I'm new to Vue.js, and I'm struggling with this simple thing.

I'd like to place a Vuetify button on my page and point it to a file, that the user can download.  The `href` part is where nothing works for me. The file to download is placed in the */assets* folder.

```
<v-btn 
   class="ma-2" 
   outlined 
   href="../assets/file.pdf" 
   target="_blank">
       Download PDF
</v-btn>
```

All it does when I click on the button is point me to a new url which is not displaying anything:

```html
http://localhost:8080/assets/file.pdf
```

Same result if I place my file to the /public directory.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should work when you place the file in *public*.  Anything in public will be in the root directory at runtime.  Change the `href` attribute to:

```html
href="file.pdf"
```

You can also remove the `target` attribute and use the `download` attribute to force a download:

```html
<a href="file.pdf" download>
   Download PDF
</a>
```

With a `v-btn` it's the same idea:

```html
<v-btn 
   class="ma-2" 
   outlined 
   href="file.pdf"
   download>
       Download PDF
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Note that no version of Internet Explorer supports the `download` attribute.